# Uninstall an app programmatically

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to develop an open source app for uninstalling applications. How can I do this?

And how can I uninstall an app that is in /system/app/ after I gain root access?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can execute `adb commands` from within your app if you have `root` access like this

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

use `try catch` as well for this code

Comment: usually u can try uninstall if u don't want to search the path of app if the app is already installed

`adb uninstall app_name`  

although i guess u want to delete `apk` file from either sys or priv-app directory then u can use following remove command in adb and try link for more details 

`adb rm [-f/-r/-d] path_of_file`  [link](http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-shell-rm)

Comment: Is there anyway to get path of an app or I should search it from "/" ?

Comment: according to my experience usually all non-os apps like bluetooth, browser  etc ( +user apps ) are kept inside `app` directory which is under `system` directory separated from other vital apps like dialer,location apps.

Answer (score 1):

After a little searching on the android developer website I found [this package installer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.html) which facilitates the installation and removal (amongst other things) of apps.

```
public class PackageInstaller
void uninstall (String packageName, 
            IntentSender statusReceiver)
```

> Uninstall the given package, removing it completely from the device.

I hope this covers your requirements.