# Double icons in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, servlets, file-upload

How do I eliminate Double icon in Android Studio? My Manifest.xml file does not contain two intent filters but I'm facing this problem.I cannot even uninstall one of the two icons created in my phone.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ico"
    android:label="StudentCertificateLedger"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/ico"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="HOMESCREEN"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignupActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".AdminDashboardActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ExtraActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".PaymentActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".UserDashboardActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".UploadActivity" />

</application>
```

Comment: "I cannot even uninstall one of the two icons created in my phone" -- what **exactly** do you mean by this? Have you looked in the list of installed apps in Settings?

Comment: There may be the cache problem. Kindly refer the below links               1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771444/how-to-self-uninstall-an-app                                                                                                         2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393847/uninstall-an-app-programmatically